# auto back to top in jquery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone there have any way that I can auto make the page back to top without refresh the page after a submit process is completed in jquery?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
$("#divid").scrollTop(0);
```

if you wnat the body do this

```
$("html,body").scrollTop(0);
```

made a sample here, scroll down there is a scroll top text ,click that

http://jsfiddle.net/D5x7F/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location='#'
```

Now it's not jquery but it's easy javascript and you can call this after your jquery is done.

Comment: this doesn't work? I just ran it in my browser, and it works. Unless we are misunderstanding your question. This code should be return you back to the top of the page whenever it's run. Can you post some html and javascript and give a detail explanation?